# Data Explorer: Large number of extents for custom partitioning policy

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

We run a fairly small V2 Kusto cluster (2-3 nodes, currently L4s). The table in question has 15TB total data, 400GB hot cache. Hot data is set to 31 days.

Because of a high query latency, we partitioned the data by device_id and a timestamp. This happened a year ago. However, we now saw this warning:

> "AttentionRequiredReason": Total extents >= 500000, Table 'mydb.mytable' has more extents per machine than recommended **(30693 >= 5000)**

Looking more closely, we have close to **2,500,000 extends** ("Total Extent Count") for this table.

This is our partitioning policy:

```json
"PartitionKeys": [
    {
        "ColumnName": "device_id",
        "Kind": "Hash",
        "Properties": {
            "Function": "XxHash64",
            "MaxPartitionCount": 256,
            "Seed": 1,
            "PartitionAssignmentMode": "Default"
        }
    },
    {
        "ColumnName": "customTimestampField",
        "Kind": "UniformRange",
        "Properties": {
            "Reference": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
            "RangeSize": "1.00:00:00",
            "OverrideCreationTime": false
        }
    }
],
```

A sample value for the timestamp field would be `2021-06-15T17:51:54.7401603Z`.

I researched a bit and saw that `"MaxPartitionCount": 256` is probably too high, given that we only have 2-3 instances configured.

My main question is: **Why do we have so many extents**? We currently get about 2.000 new extents per day. Given the partition policy, shouldn't we only get a maximum of `256` per day, because of the hash? Does it relate to the fact that the warning says 30693 extents per machine, even though we have 2.5M extents spread across two instances?

```
.show table mytable extents  
| where MaxCreatedOn > ago(90d)
| summarize count()  by bin(MaxCreatedOn, 1d)
| render timechart
```

Comment: addressing your questions without having the full context and performing deeper analysis of the cluster, its entities and their policies would be very speculative. i would recommend that you open a support request for your resource via the Azure portal to look further into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some support by Azure, and some more investigations, we found the cause:

We received a lot of messages with a custom timestamp that was not the current date. When this happens, Kusto can't merge the extents as usual and we were getting way to many of them. The solution was to set `"OverrideCreationTime": true` in our partitioning policy. This can be called [Backfill or unordered ingestion](https://yonileibowitz.github.io/blog-posts/data-partitioning.html#backfill-or-unordered-ingestion).

After fixing this, we continued to get data for past days constantly, which made it seem like we had a lot of extents even though the cluster was just not able to keep up with merging fast enough. We improved this by using a different timestamp field that was guaranteed to be close to the current date.

Comment: The default merge policy target extents with timestamps in the last 14 days. When backfilling, you'd probably want to change Lookback.Kind to all. Not sure about that when running in production with frequent very late (>14d) events.